# formulation of general dynamic programming problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I wonder if the objective function of a general dynamic programming problem can always be formulated as in [dynamic programming on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_optimality#A_dynamic_decision_problem), where the objective function is a sum of items for action and state at every stage? Or that is just a specical case and what is the general formulation?

---

EDIT:

By "dynamic programming problem", I mean a problem that can be solved by dynamic programming technique. Such kind of problems possess the property of [optimal problem and optimal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Dynamic_programming_in_computer_programming).

But at lease for me it is sometimes not easy to identify such problems, perhaps because I have not become used to that kind of verbal description. When I came across the WIKI page for Bellman equation, I do feel mathematical formulation of the cost function will help somehow.  I suspect the overall cost/gain function can always be represented as accumulation of cost/gain from all the stages? and the accumulation can be additive or multiplitive or something else?

When I posted my question, I did realize that it is more proper to discuss dynamic programming in some place more oriented to mathematical optimization. But there are quite a lot of discussion of computer algorithms in Stackoverflow.com. So I did not feel improper to ask my question here either.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. In fact, it would appear that I'm not alone in this. Maybe you should post a link to some definitions of what you're talking about? In any case, this sounds like Computer Science, and this is a *programming* web site.

Comment: @John: Computer Science and programming are very much related. The question is vague, even if you knew what the terms mean.

Comment: @Moron: He is asking if the formulation for *dynamic programming* given in the link is a special case, or if it's the general form for all dynamic-programming solutions.

Comment: @Moron: physics and Electrical Engineering are related as well, but must EE's don't do physics.

Comment: @John: Sorting algorithms, greedy algorithms, dynamic programming algoritms all fall under computer science. I supppose any question tagged algorithm must be closed now.

Comment: The phrase "dynamic programming problem" is an oxymoron. Dynamic programming is a solution approach that works well for a certain class of problems, but it is not a class of problems by itself.

Comment: @Thomas: Instead of pointlessly splitting hairs, infer the obvious intended meaning: "those problems that can be solved by dynamic programming."

Comment: @Moron: are you aware of any place to discuss computer algorithms, such as those you can learn in your "computer algorithm" course?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, I am not aware of any discussion groups specific to algorithm discussion. Perhaps google groups has one.

Comment: @Moron: "I did realize that it is more proper to discuss dynamic programming in some place more oriented to mathematical optimization". Seems the OP agrees with me. What percentage of SO users even knows what he's talking about, much less could answer his question? <0.01%, I bet. I think this question is too specialized for SO.

Comment: @John: I didn't quite agree with you. You just partially quoted what I said. You never know how diversity the background of users in this website is. Stackoverflow has surprised me so many times.

Comment: @John. You are just pulling out numbers. What % of people can answer questions about Algol? Or Fortran III, or some other niche programming language? The OP is looking at dynamic programming from one point of view, does not mean dynamic programming is not related to programming. In fact there is a lot more (programming related) to dynamic programming than just 'a mathematical optimization' and this question and answers to it might be relevant to other programmers.

Comment: @Moron: the number is a guess based on 11 month's experience on the site. I've cast my vote and we'll see what happens.

Comment: @John: Fair enough about the vote. The community has the right to decide.

Comment: @Moron: re: "The community has the right to decide". Thanks, this community member has decided. We'll now see what the other community members decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how I would characterize an arbitrary optimization problem (or a dynamic programming algorithm). In particular, the factor β<sup>*t*</sup> looks like an electrical engineering hack that programmers wouldn't usually want. More subtly, it seems like it won't always be obvious what the function *F* is for a given problem.

But yes, set β to 1 and any arbitrary objective function *can* be formulated that way. Generally the objective function may be any function of the initial state and all the actions taken; given such a function, it's easy to define a function *F* to plug into that formula.

Whether that's a useful thing to do or not depends on the problem, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! I just ignore the βt just like you set it to be 1. I interpret F as the gain/cost from one stage to the next stage. In the hindsight, I think the overall cost/gain function can always be represented as accumulation of cost/gain from all the stages? and the accumulation can be additive or multiplitive or something else?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways you could break the objective function down into per-stage pieces. The formula you cited breaks it into additive pieces; this has the advantage that it can describe every possible objective function. You could break an objective function down into per-stage factors instead, but not *every* objective function: if any move puts the objective at 0 and the next move puts it at 1, there's no possible value of *F* for that second move.

Answer (score 2):

in computer science *dynamic programming* denotes the building of any algorithm in terms of recursively splitting it into subproblems when the same subproblems appear many times in this recursive expansion. A simple book example, Fibonacci numbers can be calculated using dynamic programming:

From the generic recurrence F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) you could implement the following algorithm:

```
int fibonacci(n):
  if (n < 2): return 1
  else: return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Now this is of course not efficient at all, because it creates a huge number of recursive calls, e.g.

```
F(8) = F(7) + F(6) = [F(6) + F(5)] + [F(5) + F(4)] = ...
```

So here we already see that fibonacci(5) is computed twice by the implementation. The *dynamic programming* paradigm is now to "memoize" or "cache" the results, like this:

```
integer_map store;
int memofibo(n):
  if (n < 2) : return 1
  else if (store.find_key(n)): return store.find_value(n)
  else:
    int f = memofibo(n-1) + memofibo(n-2)
    store.set(n, f)
    return f
```

This implementation ensure that the recursive step is executed at most once for every argument value of n, so it calculates the nth Fibonacci number in O(n log n) time (assuming standard O(log n)) implementation of the associative array 'store'.

So from the computer science perspective, the link you provided is the operations research / optimization problem version of the same idea (dividing problem into subproblems), but the idea has been abstracted in practice to this recursion + memoization pattern in the domain of general computer science. I hope this helps to clear some of the clouds.

Comment: Thanks, antti! I appreciate your reply about the detail of the implementation. Yes I agree the question is more of operation research and mathematical background.

Answer (score 1):

Folks,

There's a new(ish) website that concentrates on operations research questions [here](http://www.or-exchange.com/) but the low volume of traffic there may not get you a good answer very quickly.

Soapbox time:

For those who care to debate on what's appropriate for stack overflow, let us note that an algorithm is an algorithm regardless of who claims it as part of their field.  The simplex method, Djikstra's method, branch and bound, lagrangian relaxation, are all algorithms or methods of solving certain types of problems.  Many of these are taught and applied in both fields so the border between OR and CS is pretty blurry in this area.

For instance (and a very strong instance it is) the undergrad course in algorithms at MIT includes all of the following - Randomized Competitive Algorithm, Dynamic Programming,  Greedy Algorithms, Minimum Spanning Trees, Shortest Paths, Dijkstra's Algorithm,  Bellman-Ford, Linear Programming, Depth-first Search, Topological Sort, and All-pairs Shortest Paths among other topics.   I'll defer to MIT in this case.

I like stack overflow because many programmers recognize an optimization problem when they encounter it, but often they just need a little help in deciding how to formulate the problem or even what the problem is called by name.